# Android inflated кнопки не работают

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout, android-layout-inflater

В общем пытаюсь сделать часть экрана моего приложения "пролистываемой", на каждой страничке есть кнопки. Метод **onCreate()** `MainActivity`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View main_buttons_layout_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_buttons_layout, flipper, false);
   View side_buttons_layout_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.side_buttons_layout, flipper, false);




   Button leftMouseButton = (Button) main_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.LeftMouseButtonMainButtonsLayout);
   Button rightMouseButton = (Button) main_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.RightMouseButtonTouchpad);

ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

//Первая и вторая странички с кнопками
        int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.main_buttons_layout, R.layout.side_buttons_layout};
        for (int layout : layouts)
            flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
//Обработчики
leftMouseButton.setOnTouchListener(leftMouseButtonTouchListener);

    rightMouseButton.setOnTouchListener(rightMouseButtonTouchListener);
```

В **MainActivity.xml** имеется

```
<ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"/>
```

Соответственно в **main_buttons_layout.xml** определены left mouse button и right mouse button кнопки. 
Но проблема в том, что нажатия на кнопки не работают. Дебажил, код даже не заходит в обработчики, аналогично и для кнопок второго хмл - side_buttons_layout.xml. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши разметки загружены в переменные, на них повешены слушатели, но они не добавлены в разметку экрана.

После этого вы заново загружаете эти разметки уже без слушателей на экран.

Посему и не работают слушатели, т.к. вы их не на те вьюхи, что на экране отображаются добавили.

Вот это надо убрать как лишнее:

> //Первая и вторая странички с кнопками
>
> int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.main_buttons_layout, R.layout.side_buttons_layout};
>
> for (int layout : layouts)
>
> flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));

И добавлять на экран разметку со слушателями из переменных.

```
flipper.addView(main_buttons_layout_view);
flipper.addView(side_buttons_layout_view );
```

Comment: Благодарю. Всё работает